# i want to select multiple images from phone write now i am using intent

Tags: android

I want to select multiple images from phone but I am only getting 1 image, now I am using an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();         
intent.setType("image/*");        
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

but still it only selects one image at time .so how can I set a limit on image selection more than 1 and how I can handle it in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
Which action you need to perform with multiple image,that is important

Secondly you can use Array list for same,array list of bitmap and pass that list further and you can access all that images from that list..Pls try and revert..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

//Override onActivityResult method

```
                 @Override
                  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                   if(requestCode ==1)
                  if (data != null) {
                    ClipData clipData = null;
                    try {
                         clipData = data.getClipData();
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                      if (clipData != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount();i++) {
                             // Get Uri for the image
                         Uri selectedImage = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                      try {
                      String imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, this); /* Do whatever you want to do with imagePath */
                          } 
                         catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                         }
                     }
                   }
                }
              }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI, Context context) {
    String filePath = "";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(contentURI.toString());
    if (!m.find()) {
        Log.e("", "ID for requested image not found: " +       contentURI.toString());
        return filePath;
    }
    String imgId = m.group();

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{imgId}, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();

    return filePath;


}
```